# error with SmartRefresher in flutter (Don't use one refreshController to multiple SmartRefresher,It will cause some unexpected bugs)

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

here in the controller:

```
 RefreshController refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchServices();
    fetchCategory();
    super.onInit();
  }



  Future<bool> fetchServices({bool isRefresh = false}) async {

    if (isRefresh) {
      currentPage = 1;
    } else {
      if (currentPage > totalPages) {
        refreshController.loadNoData();
        return false;
      }
    }

    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var servicesData =  await ServicesDb.fetchServices(currentPage);
      var services = servicesData.data;

      if (services != null) {

        if(isRefresh) {
          servicesList.value = services;
        } else {
          servicesList.value.addAll(services);
        }
        currentPage++;
        totalPages = servicesData.meta.lastPage;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

and in the view:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
    if(controller.isLoading.value == true || controller.isLoadingSearch.value == true) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black,));
    } else {
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: SmartRefresher(
          controller: controller.refreshController ,
          enablePullUp: true,
          onRefresh: ()=> controller.onRefresh(),
          onLoading: () => controller.onLoading(),
          child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            itemCount: controller.servicesList.length,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

i receive this error: when make hot reload, or change the oreintaion from portrait to landscape and vice versa. and when make hot reload again the error disappear>>

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Obx(has builder, state: _ObxState#8fd5c):
Don't use one refreshController to multiple SmartRefresher,It will cause some unexpected bugs mostly in TabBarView
'package:pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart':
Failed assertion: line 608 pos 12: '_refresherState == null'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Obx Obx:file:///F:/myServices/my_services/lib/ui/widgets/services_widget.dart:13:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RefreshController._bindState (package:pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart:608:12)
#3      SmartRefresherState.initState (package:pull_to_refresh/src/smart_refresher.dart:519:23)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:57)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4638:5)
...     Normal element mounting (50 frames)
#55     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3673:14)
#56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3425:18)
#57     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1242:37)
#58     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1227:20)
#59     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2573:19)
#60     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1220:12)
#61     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:349:23)
#62     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1968:59)
#63     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:916:15)
#64     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1968:14)
#65     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:338:5)
#66     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:484:5)
#67     RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:239:19)
#68     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:282:12)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#70     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#71     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#73     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#74     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1923:12)
#75     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1881:20)
#76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#85     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#86     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#91     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#92     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#93     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#95     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#96     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#97     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1097:7)
#98     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#99     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#104    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#105    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#107    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#108    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#109    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#110    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#111    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#112    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#113    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#114    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#115    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#116    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#117    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#118    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#119    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#120    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#121    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#122    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#123    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3422:13)
#124    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#125    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#126    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#127    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:745:15)
#128    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#129    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#130    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#131    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#132    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#133    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#134    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#135    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#136    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#137    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#138    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#139    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#140    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#141    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#142    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#143    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#144    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1713:7)
#145    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:885:18)
#146    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#147    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#148    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#149    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#150    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#151    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#155    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:166:10)
#156    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#157    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:129:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialized RefreshController & onRefresh function inside the Widget build(Context context)... . like this

// this is my project code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final RefreshController homeRefreshController = RefreshController();

    void onRefresh() async {
      try {
        await _homeController.getDashbaordInfo();
        homeRefreshController.refreshCompleted();
      } catch (e) {
        homeRefreshController.refreshFailed();
      }
    }
```

...

It works for me.

Comment: This works, thanks, but I suspect there's an underlying issue with widget management.

Answer (score 1):

I was using **SmartRefresher** in tab view so when ever I navigates to MainActivity in which all tabs are there **SmartRefresher** gives the same error.

This is because **SmartRefresher** lost its state.

Solution :
initialize **SmartRefresher** like this :

```
RefreshController refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
```

In my case when user logout and login again then mainactivity was giving error because it was getting previous state as I am using getx but smartrefresher has lost its state. so to solve this :

```
  logoutUser() async {
  Get.offAllNamed(Routes.ONBOARDING_SCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final _refreshControllers = <RefreshController>[
  RefreshController(...),
  RefreshController(...),
  RefreshController(...)
];
```

just create multiple RefreshController instances for each SmartRefresher.

Comment: thank you... but i have only one SmartRefresher?

Comment: sorry for that. it seems your SmartRefresher was invoked initState twice at least. Maybe when SmartRefresher is called the dispose method, the refresh controller is not destroyed synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit() : super(HomeInitial());

  static HomeCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

   late RefreshController refreshController;

}
```

inside my logic class and inside widget class

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    HomeCubit.get(context).refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SmartRefresher(controller: RefreshController(), child:YourWidget() )
```

Make your controller like that it will not lose his state anymore your welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used the same RefreshController for two or more SmartRefresher widget.

Answer (score 0):

i solve with this

```
  late RefreshController refreshController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);`
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is means you have more than one SmartRefresher() widget. But using one RefreshController().

To solve this, you must create RefreshController() for each SmartRefresher.