# Issue in declaring refreshController as a top-lever variable

Tags: flutter, dart

When I declared a list of refreshController outside my class I faced with this error:
`"Don't use one refreshController to multiple SmartRefresher,It will cause some unexpected bugs mostly in TabBarView"`
but when I created it in my class the error vanished.

I wanted to know what was the cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error with SmartRefresher in flutter (Don't use one refreshController to multiple SmartRefresher,It will cause some unexpected bugs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226139/error-with-smartrefresher-in-flutter-dont-use-one-refreshcontroller-to-multipl)

Comment: See also the discussion in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/491)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.